# Magento2 visual swatch won't change product image

Tags: magento2, product, ajax, media, color-swatches

Created a configurable product with 20 different colors in the configuration process. I added different images for each color variation but when switching from colors on the front-end the ajax script always loads the image of the first configuration.

Two examples of the ajax requests triggered after a swatch change:

> Request URL:http://domain.com/swatches/ajax/media/

**Request data**

```
product_id:553
attributes[kies_uw_kleur]:13
isAjax:true
```

**response data:**

```
{        
"large":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
"medium":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/700x560\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
"small":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/thumbnail\/88x110\/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
"gallery":{
    "1094": {"large":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
             "medium":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/700x560\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
             "small":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/thumbnail\/88x110\/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg"
             }
         }
}
```

**Request data**

```
product_id:553
attributes[kies_uw_kleur]:23
isAjax:true
```

**response data:**

```
{        
"large":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
"medium":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/700x560\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
"small":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/thumbnail\/88x110\/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
"gallery":{
    "1094": {"large":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
             "medium":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/700x560\/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg",
             "small":"http:\/\/domain.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/thumbnail\/88x110\/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582\/b\/e\/bed2-sneeuw_1.jpg"
             }
         }
}
```

So no matter the attributes id in the requested data the image of the first configured product is returned. All the different images are shown correctly in the backend.

**Magento version: 2.0.5**

**Update:**

**Changing the settings of "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" & "Used in Product Listing" in the color attribute fixed the bug... no matter the value of the two settings.**

Comment: Also i have facing this issue. but not getting what is the issue with swatches. can you suggest me what can i do ?

Comment: i also have similar issue but nothing solution found

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem! Some people are saying it comes back after cache flush or reindex however this is not the case for me.

Comment: Make sure that you have set "No" for setting "Use Product Image for Swatch if Possible".

Comment: Can you please update your progress on this issue, if you have found a solution let us know, if not can we close this out?

Comment: Well the work around in my update fixed it for me at the time. After that i abandoned Magento for this project so didn't try other solutions.

Comment: I'm faced this issue too on Magento CE 2.1.7 project. This same issue is occurred in magento default 2.1.7 also. The issue is due to vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php::loadVariationByFallback function return $this->productRepository->getById($variationProduct->getId()); correct Variation product id is not loading issue. The root cause for this issue is "Use Flat Catalog Product :: 'Yes' ". Due to this it's going to get the Simple product Id From flat table. Please try to debug the own file addFilterByParent function product collection. To fix only "Use Flat Catalog Product :: No.